# AsseticBundle Configuration - Explaination

Tags: symfony, assetic

there is no real detail in the documentation about the AsseticBundle Config - in config.yml.

```
assetic:
    debug:                "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller:
        enabled:              "%kernel.debug%"
        profiler:             false
    read_from:            "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
    write_to:             "%assetic.read_from%"
    java:                 /usr/bin/java
    node:                 /usr/bin/node
    ruby:                 /usr/bin/ruby
    sass:                 /usr/bin/sass
    # An key-value pair of any number of named elements
    variables:
        some_name:                 []
    bundles:

        # Defaults (all currently registered bundles):
        - FrameworkBundle
        - SecurityBundle
        - TwigBundle
        - MonologBundle
        - SwiftmailerBundle
        - DoctrineBundle
        - AsseticBundle
        - ...
    assets:
        # An array of named assets (e.g. some_asset, some_other_asset)
        some_asset:
            inputs:               []
            filters:              []
            options:
                # A key-value array of options and values
                some_option_name: []
    filters:

        # An array of named filters (e.g. some_filter, some_other_filter)
        some_filter:                 []
    workers:
        # see https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/pull/119
        # Cache can also be busted via the framework.templating.assets_version
        # setting - see the "framework" configuration section
        cache_busting:
            enabled:              false
    twig:
        functions:
            # An array of named functions (e.g. some_function, some_other_function)
            some_function:                 []
```

I'm specially interested in

```
 read_from:    don't understand the path, too
    write_to:
```

because I don't really understand how to use it.

So, I want to use SCSS and Compass and I have an folder in AppBundle/Resources/assets/styles/main.scss

What I have to setup in the config.yml, that assetic know how he find the main.scss as a global setting?

Comment: The one answering this question may also want to submit a PR to the docs repository. Thanks! (in other words: This question is way to broad for StackOverflow)

Comment: Thank you. Can someone, where really want to help, help me, to get assetic to work? Espessially   `read_from:`  and `write_to:  `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are trying to update the directory from which Assetic reads/writes (thus being /web by default), you don't need to change anything here. The configuration can be understood from a good part on the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html). You'll find what you need in:

```
read_from:            "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
write_to:             "%assetic.read_from%"
```

These are **paths** to a directory which is writable/readable, and exposed to the public. In this case, it means it will look for `/path/to/app/../web` for both readings and writings.

In a general manner, check for `php app/console config:dump-reference X` to find the default configuration of a given bundle, where X is the bundle config name. In your case, try the later: `php app/console config:dump-reference assetic`

Now, what you want is to use compass/sass from your view as far as I can see.
In your twig file, put the following:

```
{% stylesheets 'path/to/main.scss' filter='compass' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

After adding the configuration for compass if it needs to be tweaked, you should be all set.

Is it helping? it not, could you please provide more details?